# (HTML/CSS) Hovering “li” without hovering text from “li”

Tags: html, css

I've got a problem.

I've created an unordered list and set some list items within it and made this css for it:

```
li {
opacity: 0.5;
}

li:hover{
opacity: 1;
}
```

The problem with this is that whenever I stop hovering a pixel from a word from "li", it stops hovering the "li" and sets the opacity back to 0.5, causing a flickery effect whenever I move the mouse.
How do I make a "li" that acts like a block, so that this doesn't happen?
I've tried to create a div inside each "li" and make it div:hover but the same happened.
Thanks for the help.

FULL HTML AND CSS (margin and stuff reset css not included):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <title>Example</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="file.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <p><span>Example </span>One</p>
      <ul id="nav_bar">
        <li class="nav_button"><a>Overview</a></li>
        <li class="nav_button"><a>About</a></li>
        <li class="nav_button"><a>Help</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class "logo"><img class="logo" src="http://i.imgur.com/jufQbVj.png"></div>
      <p id="intro">Random message here.</p>
      <div id="PlayNow">Click here to x!</div>
      <p id="versao">For bla bla<p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

font-face {
  font-family: UbuntuR;
  src: url(Ubuntu-R.ttf);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: UbuntuB;
  src: url(Ubuntu-B.ttf);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: UbuntuL;
  src: url(Ubuntu-L.ttf);
}

body{
  background-color: #e4a714;
  cursor: default;
}

.header {
  padding: 16px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #231f20;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.header span{
  font-family: UbuntuB;
}

#nav_bar .nav_button {
  display:inline-block;
  padding-left: 6px;
  padding-right: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-family: UbuntuL;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#nav_bar .nav_button:hover{
  opacity: 1;
}

.logo{
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-bottom: -90px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}

.header p{
  color: white;
  font-family: UbuntuL;
  font-size: 26px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
}

#intro {
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  font-size: 38px;
  font-family: "Segoe WP", "Segoe UI Light", "Segoe UI", "Helvetica Neue", "Arial", sans-serif;
}

#PlayNow {
  background-color: #e4a714;
  font-family: UbuntuL;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 24px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#PlayNow:hover {
  background-color: #ffbb16;
}

#versao {
  font-family: font-family: "Segoe WP", "Segoe UI Light", "Segoe UI", "Helvetica Neue", "Arial", sans-serif;
  margin-top: 6px;
  font-size: 16px;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

Remove:

```
<div class "logo"><img class="logo" src="http://i.imgur.com/jufQbVj.png"></div>
```

from code and it starts working as it should.

Any recommendations to what I'm doing wrong would help too. Thanks.

Comment: Mind providing an [example](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: How can I upload my folder here?

Comment: You can't. But you can provide your relevant HTML/CSS.

Comment: So apparently this stops happening when I remove the image, which is like 30px under the actual text.. Not sure why..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to clear margin-top: -50.
The image margin covers the unordered list, that cause the fade in-out effect.

If you need the logo get closer to menu, than you have to edit it with photo editor.

Comment: Could please explain why this is supposed to work, so that someone can actually learn from your answer.

Comment: Sorry, my english poor, but the explain is in the answer: The question was: ,,How do I make a "li" that acts like a block". that way: display: block

Comment: Don't worry about your english, I'm als not a native speaker ;)
It's just that only posting a code snippet, even if it's an obvious answer, isn't really _helping_ people who have no clue whats going on :)

Comment: I already have display: inline-block; on my code, but it still "flickers" when I have an image some pixels under it. See the main message. Thanks

Comment: The margin is probably it.. I just set it to 0, from -50 and -90, but now there is way too much space.. What can I do to remove it? Why is it even there?

Comment: Yes. The image margin covers the unordered list, that cause the fade in-out effect.